# TypeScript - how to throw compile time error if two types intersect?

Tags: typescript, types

say,

```
type a = 'type1' | 'type2';
type b = 'type1' | 'type3';
type combined = a | b;
```

is there any way in typescript to get compile time error for the above example - any case where two types overlap?

Comment: You could get never with something like: `type Foo<A, B> = (A & B) extends never ? A | B : never;` ? If that's helpful?

Comment: @Yoshi you can post it as an answer

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Yoshi! This works great for 2 types (A+B) but if you have say 15 types, then you need to find the types that exist in at least two unions out of all the 15 types. This is a very hard problem, and at this point we gave up.

Instead, we just added a unit test which checks at runtime for name clashes between types.